# Why can't I sort pairs with a const-specified element type?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std-pair

I was trying to sort the elements of a `std::map<char, int>` descending by value. In order to do this, I copied the key-value pairs into a `std::vector<std::map<char, int>::value_type>` and tried to sort this. Then I received a wall of text of compiler error (see at the bottom).

Apparantly `std::map<char, int>::value_type` resolves to `std::pair<const char, int>`, and it seems the errors that `std::sort` throw are caused by the `const` specifier for the key-type of the map. As it works just fine when I use `std::pair<char, int>` instead.

This is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using pair_type = std::pair<const char, int>; // fails to compile
    //using pair_type = std::pair<char, const int>; // fails to compile
    //using pair_type = std::pair<char, int>; // works

    std::vector<pair_type> to_be_sorted = {{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}};

    std::sort(to_be_sorted.begin(), to_be_sorted.end(),
        [](pair_type const& a, pair_type const& b) { return a.second > b.second; }
    );
}
```

Why can't I use the `std::map<char, int>::value_type` directly? Why does `std::sort` fail to compile when one of the pair elements has a `const`-specified type?

The compiler error looks like this:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1885:25:   required from ‘void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1971:31:   required from ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)>]’
tt.cc:13:90:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1852:17: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<const char, int>& std::pair<const char, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const char, int>&)’
        *__first = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__val);
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/utility:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:60,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:208:12: note: ‘std::pair<const char, int>& std::pair<const char, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const char, int>&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘std::pair<const char, int>’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
     struct pair
            ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_heap.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__pop_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1675:19:   required from ‘void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1933:25:   required from ‘void std::__partial_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1948:27:   required from ‘void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Size = long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:25:   required from ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)>]’
tt.cc:13:90:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_heap.h:252:17: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<const char, int>& std::pair<const char, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const char, int>&)’
       *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:61,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _ForwardIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:84:20:   required from ‘void std::__move_median_to_first(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Iterator, _Iterator, _Compare) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1921:34:   required from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1953:38:   required from ‘void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Size = long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:25:   required from ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)>]’
tt.cc:13:90:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:148:11: error: use of deleted function ‘typename std::enable_if<(! std::__and_<std::__is_swappable<_T1>, std::__is_swappable<_T2> >::value)>::type std::swap(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const char; _T2 = int; typename std::enable_if<(! std::__and_<std::__is_swappable<_T1>, std::__is_swappable<_T2> >::value)>::type = void]’
       swap(*__a, *__b);
       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/utility:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:60,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:503:5: note: declared here
     swap(pair<_T1, _T2>&, pair<_T1, _T2>&) = delete;
     ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_heap.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Distance = long int; _Tp = std::pair<const char, int>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_heap.h:342:22:   required from ‘void std::__make_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1672:23:   required from ‘void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1933:25:   required from ‘void std::__partial_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1948:27:   required from ‘void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Size = long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:25:   required from ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)>]’
tt.cc:13:90:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_heap.h:225:29: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<const char, int>& std::pair<const char, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const char, int>&)’
    *(__first + __holeIndex) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first + __secondChild));
                             ^
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_heap.h:231:29: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<const char, int>& std::pair<const char, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const char, int>&)’
    *(__first + __holeIndex) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first
                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:61,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘static _BI2 std::__copy_move_backward<true, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_move_b(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = std::pair<const char, int>*; _BI2 = std::pair<const char, int>*]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:588:37:   required from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true; _BI1 = std::pair<const char, int>*; _BI2 = std::pair<const char, int>*]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:598:5:   required from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a2(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true; _BI1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _BI2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:668:48:   required from ‘_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _BI2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1851:8:   required from ‘void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1885:25:   required from ‘void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1971:31:   required from ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)>]’
tt.cc:13:90:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:548:18: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<const char, int>& std::pair<const char, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const char, int>&)’
      *--__result = std::move(*--__last);
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_heap.h:128:5: warning: ‘void std::__push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Distance = long int; _Tp = std::pair<const char, int>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’ used but never defined
     __push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:61,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/predefined_ops.h:169:7: warning: ‘__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<_Compare>::_Iter_comp_val(__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>&&) [with _Compare = main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)>]’ used but never defined
       _Iter_comp_val(_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>&& __comp)
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:1821:5: warning: ‘void std::__unguarded_linear_insert(_RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<const char, int> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)> >]’ used but never defined
     __unguarded_linear_insert(_RandomAccessIterator __last,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:61,
                 from tt.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/predefined_ops.h:225:5: warning: ‘__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<_Compare> __gnu_cxx::__ops::__val_comp_iter(__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>) [with _Compare = main()::<lambda(const pair_type&, const pair_type&)>]’ used but never defined
     __val_comp_iter(_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare> __comp)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: How would you swap `const` elements?

Comment: Sorting requires replacing one value with another, it calls `x = y` at some point. If `x` is const (or x.Z is const) this obviously fails.

Comment: @moooeeeep Do you want to sort only the second elements of pairs?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I needed the whole pairs.

Comment: @moooeeeep When you need not to sort. Just create a new map with the comparison function std::greater

Comment: `std::map` is already sorted (ascending).  To get the values in descending order, use the reverse iterators (`rbegin()` and `rend()`)

Comment: @BenVoigt The extra sort is supposed to order the items wrt. the second element of the pair, instead of the first.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ah - I misunderstood. Yes it is supposed to order the items wrt. the second element only...